¿Cómo puedo hacer que las URL remotas de vite module federation sean dinámicas según el entorno (local, QA, development)?
Hola estoy trabajando con react vite module federation, tengo 5 microfrontends y me encuentro con un problema, necesito configurar mi vite.config.ts para que las url de los microfrontends remotos las tome dependiendo del ambiente ya sea QA, development, local, prod.
Este es mi vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
import packageJson from "./package.json";
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: "remote-user-management",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        remoteUtilities: "http://localhost:5001/assets/remoteEntry.js",
        store: "http://localhost:5000/assets/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      exposes: {
        "./mf-user-management": "./src/main.tsx",
        "./mf-user-management-store": "./src/store/Register/registerSlice.ts",
        "./mf-maintainer-store": "./src/store/RegisterProfile/registerProfile.ts"
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
});

Intente creando archivos .env.development así para cada ambiente colocando las rutas y luego intentando con process.env o import.meta.env traer esas variables dependiendo del script que se envie pero no logro capturar la variable de entorno, me llega como undefined, alguien tiene una opción para que esto funcione?

No se en vite, pero en otros lenguajes se configuran estas cosas con variables de entorno... Vite no tiene algo de eso?

Hice la configuración con variables de entorno solo que en vite no se usa process.env para acceder a ellas si no import.meta.env pero en el archivo de vite.config no me acepta el meta.env

Hola, haciendo referencia a la documentación de vite: https://es.vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode#archivos-env cuando a una variable de entorno no le pones prefijo "VITE_" estas no serán visibles para el entorno procesado con vite. Siendo de esta forma, prueba poner en tus archivos .env las variables de esta forma:
VITE_MFURL1  = https://localhost:5000/some/path
y en tu vite.config para importarlas:
import.meta.env.VITE_MFURL1

@saul_chavin Hola, si ya las tengo de esa manera mira, VITE_REMOTE_PARENT_URL incluso si en mi app.tsx  pongo   console.log('VITE_REMOTE_PARENT_URL :', import.meta.env.VITE_REMOTE_PARENT_URL ); si me sale la ruta perfectamente pero en el vite.config no lo toma

entiendo @RafaelMonroyRodriguez necesitarías llamar la función loadEnv como lo indica aqui: https://v4.vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config

Es necesario llamar a la función loadEnv y pasar como parámetro a la función defineConfig una función anónima en donde tomes el mode para cargar ya sea el archivo .env.production o .env.development
quedando el archivo vite.config.ts de la siguiente manera:
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')
  return {
    plugins: [
      react(),
      federation({
       //tus configuraciones
        remotes: {
          remoteUtilities: env.REMOTE_UTILITIES,
          store: env.STORE,
        },
      }),
    ],
  }
})


También es probable que el editor muestre un error al usar process de node diciendo que no esta definido, si es el caso, se soluciona simplemente instalando la dependencia @types/node como una dependencia de desarrollo.
